# Stop iisexpress site when I stop debugging it? VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, iis-express

I have a VS2010 web project that I debug with iisexpress.

Sometimes when stepping code I notice something wrong that would have undesirable effects, e.g. in my 70 Gigabyte database, so I want to stop the code.

My reflex action is to stop debugging in VS2010, but this has the effect that the debugger detaches from the process, and that causes the code to continue running at full speed and do that thing I wanted to avoid.

So, is there any way to get the site to stop instead of continue running at full speed, when I stop debugging in VS?

Note: I don't lose any data or anything - it's safe test data. But due to the large database size, restoring a new test database is a big waste of time.

Note 2: I know I can stop iisexpress in various ways instead of stoppping the debugger in VS. The problem is that I keep forgetting this, and remember only after the damage is done.

So, please, no suggestions that tell med how to stop iisexpress manually or how to protect my database. Only try to answer the actual question: how to AUTOMATICALLY stop the site from executing when I hit "stop debugging" inside VS. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Other than with a third party or otherwise bespoke program (or script configured to run on debugger attachment (?)), let me disregard your demand to *only* answer the question exactly and provide another thought at least...

In an emergency, step through the code with the debugger and upon noticing the potential detriment manually move the execution scope to, say the end of the method, essentially skipping the code you don't want to run.

So, say if a page does something in the load event, move to the closing brace of the event handler code and then continue, the page will load minus the code having been executed.

Comment: Thanks, but I know that and a lot of other options along the same lines, but it doesn't help when my fingers hit "Stop debugging" before I have time to think it through. :-)

By the way, the script, if any, would have to run on debugger DEtachment.